# Resetting cursor in Reader

Tags: go

I am working on a program to read from a csv file. I am encountering a strange EOF error and was wondering if there was a way to reset the line cursor of `*csv.Reader` to the beginning of the file without creating a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `io.Reader` you are passing to `csv.NewReader` is a `io.File` then you can call `Seek(0, 0)` on it to reset it back to the start.

Not sure how this will work with CSV though since the parser may already know that it has read the first line. I guess you could skip over that by reading it.

Comment: Brilliant! That did it! Thank you so much!